# How does Outlook insert "magic" addresses into To field?

Tags: c#, forms, outlook-addin

How do Outlook's `TextBox` objects intelligently know that contact information has been added and that it corresponds to existing `ContactItem`s?

[image]

How can I duplicate this behavior for a custom form region using C#?

```
private void FooButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Outlook.Application Application = new Outlook.Application();
    // Add ListView's selected items to BarTextBox
}
```